# Sort a group, depending on key

Tags: laravel

I have a seller list, who are paying service charge. I am listing the service charge according the year. Suppose seller A,C,D paid service charge in 2021, Seller B,E,F in 2022. I want to group them and show in list. Till grouping its okay. The problem I am facing is, The record group is showing 2021 first then 2022, it's showing the group in ascending order. But I want it in descending order.

Controller

```
public function service(){
   $infos = ServiceCharge::all()->groupBy('year');
   $sellerInfo = Seller_info::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
   return view('Backend.pages.account.service',compact('infos','sellerInfo'));
}
```

If I use this

```
$infos = ServiceCharge::orderBy('year','DESC')->groupBy('year')->get();
dd($infos);
```

It shows [only one value, The first entered value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Ykr.png)

but without groupBy

```
$infos = ServiceCharge::orderBy('year','DESC')->get();
dd($infos);
```

it shows [all the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kaEE.png). I entered 2 value. This is my [inserted data formation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzTpm.png)
How can I print this in latest year order?

Comment: "_but it shows error_" What would that error be?

Comment: I edited the question to show the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `get` method instead of `all`:

```
$infos = ServiceCharge::groupBy('year')->orderBy('year','DESC')->get();
```

Comment: it shows -> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'samikh.service_charges.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `service_charges` group by `year` order by `year` desc)" this error

Comment: if I change in config/database.php it shows the value but only one value.

Comment: @SaymaObaida `get` returns all rows in a collection. If your query return just one row, it depends on your data (or your group by is not true).

Comment: I edited on the question. Please you may check.

Comment: Its getting all the groups, like 2020, 2021, 2022. But one data in each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
$infos = ServiceCharge::orderBy('year','DESC')->get()->unique('year');
```

or

```
 $infos = ServiceCharge::orderBy('year','DESC')->groupBy('year')->get();
```

Comment: for first case it shows this error ->Attempt to read property "amount" on bool , for second case it shows ->SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'samikh.service_charges.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `service_charges` group by `year` order by `year` desc)