# GroupBy doesn't show all the data

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a list of sellers, where everyone paying service charge. I want to show the service charge grouped by year in descending order. The group's year should be in descending order. Like, I inputed data for 2023, 2020, 2021. The group data should show 2023 first then 2021, then 2020. First I tried with

```
$infos = Commision::all()->groupBy('country');
```

If I use order first it shows error. I have a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70516545/sort-a-group-depending-on-key). The I tried with

```
$infos = DB::table('service_charges')->groupBy('year')->orderBy('year','DESC')->get();
dd($infos);
```

But its show's only one data of each group. I have 3 data saved [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh3b1.png) . 2 is from 2021, 1 is from 2020. But the query showing me only one data from each group [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq4uI.png).

Comment: have you tried this 
$infos = DB::table('service_charges')->orderBy('year','DESC')->get()->groupBy('year');

Comment: I am ashamed of myself. It works thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `GROUP BY` SQL statement is used to aggregate data that have the same value for a given column. That means you can only get a single aggregated result of the data for each distinct value in that column (i.e. one value per year in your case).

The collection `groupBy` is used to group all data in their own collection if they have the same value. However the difference is that `groupBy` in the collection runs after the query so you can no longer `orderBy` at that point. Here are two ways you might be able to solve your issue:

1. Order in the query then group the resulting collection

```
$infos = DB::table('service_charges')->orderBy('year','DESC')->get()->groupBy('year');
```

2. Sort and order the resulting collection

```
$infos = Commision::all()->groupBy('country')->sortKeysDesc();
```